# How to trigger function from another file in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table-next to create a table. There is `columns` prop in `BootstrapTable` and it accept an **array**. I want to keep the **columns array** in a separate file as the array will be too big in the future.

When the user clicks on the `text-3` field, the `onClick` function works. But I want to see this in home.tsx too, because I will use this data. What I need is to trigger somewhere in home.tsx when it is triggered in columns.tsx. When triggered, I'll use that data in home.tsx. How can i do that?

**home.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next'
import { dataColumns } from '../../columns/columns'
import { homeData} from '../../data/data'

const Home: React.FC = () => {

const triggeredFunction = () => {
 //I want this function triggered
}
return (
         <BootstrapTable
              bordered
              striped
              hover
              columns={dataColumns}
              data={homeData}
         />
)
}

export default Home
```

**columns.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'

export const dataColumns = [
      {
         text: 'text-1',
         dataField: 'text1'
      },
      {
         text: 'text-2',
         dataField: 'text2'
      },
      {
         text: 'text-3'
         dataField: 'text3',
         events: {
              onClick: (e:any, row:any) => {
                 //This is the first triggered function
                 return {
                        e:e,
                        row: row
                 }
              }
         }
      }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that function in the *props*. And can call that function as `onClick = {props.myFunction()}`. Hope this might help you

Comment: columns.tsx is not a Component. So, I can not pass function